# Can I execute a method everytime I get an exception on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried almost everything on web, all I want is to call a method whenever an exception like "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" or "No route matches" appears.

Rescues from ApplicationController does not work, but why?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private
    def self.send_report_error(message)
      Notifier.page_failure(message).deliver
    end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # handle not found error
  send_report_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.to_s
rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
  # handle other ActiveRecord errors
  send_report_error ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError.to_s
rescue # StandardError
  # handle most other errors
  send_report_error "common error"
rescue Exception
  # handle everything else
  send_report_error "common exception"
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `rescue_from`.  For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :send_report_error
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html